# Spring Boot RestTemplate deserialization issue

Tags: spring-boot, resttemplate

I have following Class

```
public class RestResponseDto {

    private Boolean status;
    private Object data;
    private Object error;


    public RestResponseDto(Boolean status, Object data, Object error) {
        this.status = status;
        this.data = data;
        this.error = error;
    }

         //Getters and setters

}
```

I am trying to hit my another REST API (GET REQUEST) and map the response to this Class.

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        RestResponseDto result = restTemplate.getForObject(uri, RestResponseDto.class);
```

But I am getting the following error :

```
Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Can not construct instance of xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: no suitable constructor found, can not deserialize from Object value (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?);
```

Comment: Do you have a default no-args constructor?

Answer (score 1):

For response to be mapped to your custom DTO, you should have default constructor for given DTO. In `RestResponseDto`  there is no default constructor defined. So change it to:

```
public class RestResponseDto {

    private Boolean status;
    private Object data;
    private Object error;

    public RestResponseDto() {
    }
    public RestResponseDto(Boolean status, Object data, Object error) {
        this.status = status;
        this.data = data;
        this.error = error;
    }
         //Getters and setters
}
```

Comment: That's a horrible advice. You don't just haphazardly throw in a default constructor, unless you want to make sure you introduce some bugs down the road. Either use a default constructor _only_ or have it set up default values or don't have one at all and find another way to inject the values.